# Jquery popups with load()

Tags: jquery, popup, load

I have a few different divs with different projects and names. Each one has a unique name, and I would like that when a user clicks on one, that it loads the appropriate page into the `popupContainer` div. For some reason it is not calling though.

This is the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Find & Open
    $(".projectThumb").click(function(){
        htmlName = $(this).find("img").attr("name");
        $("#popupContainer").load(htmlName + ".html");
            });
    //Close property
    $("a.close").live("click", function(){
        $("#popupContainer").empty();
        });
});
```

This is the html:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="projectThumb">
    <img src="/img/aeffect_button_static.gif" width="146" height="199" class="button" name="aeffect" alt="" />
    <p class="title">A.EFFECT: Film Poster</p>
    </div>
    <div class="projectThumb">
    <img src="/img/lova_button_static.gif" width="229" height="199" class="button" name="lova" alt="" />
    <p class="title">Lova &ndash; Summer 07&rsquo; &ndash; Titles</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="popupContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Do you see the request in firebug going through?  What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Nope, the request isn't being sent through. Something isn't being called correctly.

Comment: I created a page with the exact same html and jQuery and it worked perfectly.  Or at least updated the popupContainer with the dummy text I'd placed in the correspending files it loads. Of course I having implemented any stylesheets. So is the problem actually CSS related?

Comment: Hm, seems the problem is actually my not closing other properties within some other code in the .js. This works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not closing your 1st click function and you're not opening the `ready(function(){...})` correctly either:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // <-- added missing open parens
 //Find & Open
 $(".projectThumb").click(function(){
   htmlName = $(this).find("img").attr("name");
   $("#popupContainer").load(htmlName + ".html");
 }); // <-- added needed closing function

 //Close property
 $("a.close").live("click", function(){
   $("#popupContainer").empty();
 });
});
```

Comment: corrected these as they were typos when I was inputting the code to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Tag

```
<img ... >
```

has no attribute "name" (only form and its components), use "id" :)

Answer (score 0):

Your not closing your 1st click function:

```
$(document).ready(function){
 //Find & Open
 $(".projectThumb").click(function(){
   htmlName = $(this).find("img").attr("name");
   $("#popupContainer").load(htmlName + ".html");
 }); <-- needed

 //Close property
 $("a.close").live("click", function(){
   $("#popupContainer").empty();
 });
});
```

Comment: Almost there but no banana... the first function passed to "ready" is ill-defined

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, I just mistyped it, I edited the original to reflect my code.